# What is the max amount of users that can build a game using Team Create?

Tags: roblox

Since I am planning on a bigger development course with Roblox, I need to know the limitations of Team Create to account for that accordingly.

However [the official website](https://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Team_Create) does not mention any such number, or any other limitations (other than the current lock on script files to a single user).

So what would be the max amount of users? (Practically and feasibly?)

Comment: I'd assume the limit is what you would have set as the maximum amount of players in the server.

Comment: I don't know... I would assume that a "game server" is very different from the "team create server"... but there is really surprisingly little information on some of the most fundamental aspects of Team Create

Comment: **Short Answer:** There isn't a limit. |
How many players are you planning to log onto your team create system?
There shouldn't be a "limit" (meaning past 50 players is outright beyond any one's limit) to the team create.